# CCAnimate with sprite file names?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

CCAnimate requires CCSpriteFrames, while they require a texture2d.

Is it not possible to simply use CCAnimate by providing my file names? Like anim1.png, anim2.png, anim3.png...

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

If you are on versions 0.99.*, you can load the files into `UIImage`s, then create `CCTexture2D`s using the `initWithImage:` function, then create `CCSpriteFrame`s.

If you are on version 1.0.0 or later, you can load the textures from files using the `CCTextureCache` singleton, then create `CCSpriteFrame`s.

However, the whole point behind this API is that you can place all the frames of your animation into one image file, load it as a texture, and then carve out the individual frames using the `rect` property/argument. This should also improve performance, since the graphics chip only has to load one texture and then perform cheap clipping operation instead of loading multiple textures.

**EDIT**: Cocos2D has a function for [direct CCSpriteFrame loading](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/interface_c_c_sprite_frame.html#a2fa3b38c59f2526ae666ed4c49fa94f1) since version 1.1.

Comment: But what if the image file where all my images are located is simply massive? So huge that it gives memory warnings?

Comment: Then, of course, you can split it up into multiple files -- let's say one file for the first twenty-five frames, another for the next twenty-five frames, etc. One file per frame is probably overkill, though.

Comment: That's what I don't quite get: splitting? I mean, I need to create a CCSpriteBatchNode for this stuff, and then add my CCSprite as child of it, right? If that's the case, how can I use two different files if CCSpriteBatchNode only accepts one?

Comment: I don't think so -- `CCSpriteFrame` should take care of that automatically. A hierarchy of `CCTexture2D* -> CCSpriteFrame* -> CCAnimation -> CCAnimate` should be sufficient.

Comment: In 0.99.x I've been using:

    phaseAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"pearl" delay:(1/18.0f)]; 
    [phaseAnimation retain];
    [phaseAnimation addFrameWithFilename:@"phase0001.png"];

I received notices/warnings that the functions are deprecated but they still work... 
    [phaseAnimation addFrameWithFilename:@"phase0002.png"];